# How to make at least one argument required and have the possibility to take all arguments with argparse in Python?

Tags: python, argparse

The program has 2 arguments to deal with: state and key.
I need to have a possibility to give as input the following options:

- prog -state state_value
- prog -key key_value
- prog -state state_value -key key_value

The closest thing is using mutually excluding groups, but it unables the possibility to give 
both arguments as input at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is beyond the abilities of argparse. You could perform a simple validation on the returned namespace afterwards though. You should include in your help that at least once of state or key is required.

```
def validate(namespace, parser):
    if not any(arg in {"state", "key"} for arg in vars(namespace).keys()):
        parser.print_help()
        parser.exit(2)

namespace = parser.parse_args()
validate(namespace, parser)
```

Comment: Unless you are using SUPPRESS, each argument will appear in the `namespace`, with at least its default value (e.g. `None`).  So testing for the presence of `keys` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24911007/901925 there isn't a built in mechanism for testing this, but it is easy to make such a test after parsing.  Assuming the arguments have the default `default` of `None`, such a test could be:

```
if args.state is None and args.key is None:
    parser.error('At least one of the arguments is required ')
```

---

Eventually `argparse` might have such a mechanism.  There is a bug request for more testing power in groups, http://bugs.python.org/issue11588

One idea is to add UsageGroups, modeled on mutually exclusive groups, but with more general logic.  The code isn't available for download, but I'd be interested in hearing whether this example is clear.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='prog')
group = parser.add_usage_group(kind='any', required=True)
group.add_argument('-s', '--state', metavar='state_value')
group.add_argument('-k', '--key', metavar='key_value')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

with an error message:

```
usage: prog [-h] (-s state_value | -k key_value)
prog: error: group any(): some of the arguments [state, key] is required
```

An alternative in the usage line is `(-s state_value, -k key_value)`, since `|` is already being used for the mutually exclusive `xor` relation.  The `usage` and error message could be customized.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys

paras = sys.argv.pop(0)
state_value = None
key_value = None
i=0
while i < len(paras):
    if paras[i] == '-state':
        state_value = paras[i]
    elif paras[i] == '-key':
        key_value = paras[i]
    i += 2

if state_value:
    # do something
    pass
if key_value:
    # do something
    pass
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the current situation.
There is a variety of values that a 'state' and 'key' can take and user gives them as an input depending on the needs.

The help info is there, the only problem is to make a program work with at least 1 value or both of them.

Comment: OK, just make your code clear next time. I've updated my answer.