# Is there an other way to parse args with groups?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, argparse, args

I just tried those:

```python
arg = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Corpse v0.1a Stable Alpha Experiment')
arg.add_argument('--about', help = 'About author and license information.', action = 'store_true')

gr_root = arg.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

gr_render = gr_root.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
gr_render.add_argument('-r', '--render', help = 'A raw text to render it into a corpus database.')
gr_render.add_argument('--append', help = 'If there is already a database, this option will be useful.', action = 'store_true')

gr_load = gr_root.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
gr_load.add_argument('-l', '--load', help = 'A database name to report the content.')
gr_load.add_argument('-p', '--pattern', help = 'The token pattern that is needed to be reported.')
gr_load.add_argument('--less', help = 'List the pattern that is "less and equal" than the count.', action = 'store')
gr_load.add_argument('--more', help = 'List the pattern that is "more and equal" than the count.', action = 'store')

args = vars(arg.parse_args())
```

I used a question in this platform, but I do not remember which it is. When I use add_mutually_exclusive_group(), it seems it seperates group arguments with "OR" operator. I understand it with this output I get:

```
usage: corpse.py [-h] [--about] [[-r RENDER | --append]
                 [-l LOAD | -p PATTERN | --less LESS | --more MORE]
corpse.py: error: argument --append: not allowed with argument -r/--render
```

However, I want to seperate arguments to the groups to use them together which means I want this:

```
[-r RENDER & --append]
```

Not this:

```
[-r RENDER | --append]
```

I mean I use *render* and *append* argument together and **not with *load*, *pattern*, *less* and *more***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bugs.python.org/issue22047 explains your difficulty with nested groups.  Note the `[[` in the usage.

Your best bet for now is to test after parsing.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24915802/901925.

What would the ideal usage line look like?

---

Here's a rough sketch of a subparser based solultion:

```
parser = ArguementParser()
sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')

sp.add_parser('about')

spp = sp.add_parser('load', help='report content of a database')
spp.add_argument('database')
spp.add_argument('--pattern', ...)
spp.add_argument('--less', ...)
spp.add_argument('--more', ...)

spp = sp.add_parser('render', help='render text into a database')
spp.add_argument('text')
spp.add_argument('--append',...)
```

Comment: There are actually three groups: [--about] | [--render & --append] | [--load & --pattern & --less & more]

To see about section:
`myscr.py --about`

To load any text:
`myscr.py --load text.txt # Creates A Database Names text.db`
`myscr.py --load text.txt --append some.db # Appends Some DB or Creates A DB Named As In --append Argument`

To load a database:
`myscr.py --load any.db`

_pattern_, _less_ and _more_ arguments are not that important. Those are what I **do not** want:

`myscr.py --about --render some.txt`
`myscr.py --render some.txt --load any.db` etc...

Comment: Actually now I think the solution. What about seperate every group to another dict? I mean there is an _args_ variable in the code above which is a dict and contains all arguments. I think creating three dicts and seperating every group into those dicts will solve problem. Just like [this](http://kl1p.com/woVd).

Comment: Actually that does not work. It will not raise an error. It's just like writing all the _argparse_ from the beginning.

Comment: With your added examples, I think this would fit the subparsers pattern.  You in effect have 3 commands: `about`, `load`, `render`.  `render` takes a positional and 1 optional. `load` takes a positional and 2 optionals.

Comment: I'm thinking of writing an argparse bug issue suggesting that a mutually exclusive group reject the nesting of another group.

Comment: I think the code above will save the day. Now I just wonder if they can overcome this bug and is there still a bug in Python 3.x. Whatever, thanks again. :)